# TS18048: '' is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using TypeScript, but I got an error "TS18048: 'record.childList1' is possibly 'undefined'.", which I guess it caused due to childList1 was optional in CheckListItemVO. I tried to write

1. record.childList1[0]?.pciName
2. (record.childList1[0] as CheckListItemChildVO).pciName

but sill get the same error.

Here is my code

```
<Table.Column
   key='childList1'
   dataIndex='childList1'
   title={<div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>standard</div>}
   render={(text, record: CheckListItemVOExtender) => (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
      <p style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }}>{record.childList1[0].pciName}</p>              
      </div>)}
/>

type CheckListItemVOExtender = CheckListItemVO & {
  sparPoint: string | number;
};

export type CheckListItemVO = CCheckListItem & {
  childList1?:CheckListItemChildVO[]; 
}

export type CCheckListItem = {
  pciName?:string; 
}
```

Most of time, when I get the error, I put optional mark or did put "as Type" at the end (like second method), but it did not work in this case.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Why is `childList1` an array if you're only interested in the first element?

Comment: Where is the type for `CheckListItemChildVO`? Did you mean `CCheckListItem` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Optional chaining with expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#optional_chaining_with_expressions).

> You can also use the optional chaining operator with bracket notation, which allows passing an expression as the property name
> ...
> This is particularly useful for **arrays**, since array indices must be accessed with brackets

The safe syntax would be...

```ts
record.childList1?.[0]?.pciName
```

- The first `?.[0]` is used because `childList1` may be undefined.
- The second `?.pciName` is used because even if `childList1` is an array, it may be empty and `[0]` could also be undefined.

---

But why is `childList1` an array if you're only interested in the first element?

It's typical to iterate arrays, for example

```tsx
<div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
  {record.childList1?.map(({ pciName }, index) => (
    <p key={index} style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }}>
      {pciName}
    </p>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: My code I posted was just simple because I deleted a lot of code. I use childList1 in different places as well. Thank you for helping me out, I will try your suggestions !!!

Comment: oh, well. your method is working well, thank you !!, but I kinda do not understand what it means for childList1?.[0]. childList1 is an array but how can we put .(dot) before [0] ...? wasn't it supposed to be childList1[0] or something?

Comment: Did you not read the direct documentation link I provided?

Comment: I just read the docs and your additional information. now I understand better. Thank you so much and have a good day !! :DD